# Floating excel table that updates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small table in excel that I want to always be visible when scrolling through the worksheet and update as changes are made from the general worksheet. VBA help please.

Answer (score 1):

## Freeze Panes

Move your table to the top left region of your worksheet and select the cell to the **right** and **down** from the last cell of your table and choose `Window>Freeze Panes`.

The image shows an example where the table is in range A1:G16. Now you have to select cell H17 and choose `Window>Freeze Panes`.

[image]